# SSDT unresolved reference with dacpac references

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2012, sql-server-data-tools

I have an SSDT project where I recently changed from SQL 2008 to SQL 2012. I re-exported my references DACPAC files using the SQL 2012 SqlPackage and replaced the SQL 2008 DACPACs with the new 2012 versions. Now I am getting unresolved reference errors for all of the referenced databases.

Strangely enough, IntelliSense auto complete works with the objects in the DACPACs. I can get all tables and columns to auto-complete and show their datatypes, even on the object SSDT is complaining about.

Is there a know issue with SSDT when migrating versions? I have another project using these DACPACs and it builds without error.

Comment: Did you try to Clean and then Build again?

Comment: Check once your target platform.

Answer (score 0):

I would do three things, the first is double check that each dacpac is at 2012 - when I had a mixed project it was a nightmare, mixing versions causes all sorts of issues with references.

Secondly, open each of the dacpacs as a project in Visual studio and make sure that each of them build correctly, it might be a reference from one of those to something in master etc that is causing subsequent build failures.

Finally do a clean of the solution and build just the dacpac project, look for any messages or warnings in the output window, the answer will be there but just hard to see.

ed

Comment: DACPACS were exported from a database with compat level 2012 set on a SQL 2012 instance. Project compat is set to SQL 2012 as well.

Comment: There is no project for these DACPACs. I could import the existing database and build that; however it is a vendor database which will most definitely fail a build due to... well, superior database design practices.

Comment: lol, i've been there (and am there now!) - put the vendor stuff in a seperate dacpac, anything that doesn't compile delete or comment - this will make your life easier I promise